# Descomponer una lista

Tags: r

Creo una lista y le añado df

```
lista <-list()

d1 <-data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3))
d2 <-data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3))
d3 <-data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3))
d4 <-data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3))


lista[["d1"]] <-d1
lista[["d2"]] <-d2
lista[["d3"]] <-d3
lista[["d4"]] <-d4
```

Borro los df

```
rm(d1,d2,d3,d4)
```

Partiendo de la lista, ¿cómo puedo volver a tener los df por separados?

Podría hacer

```
lista[[1]]-> d1
lista[[2]]-> d2
.
.
.
```

Pero si son muchos, ¿hay algo que lo descomponga de manera rápida?
Se me ocurre con un bucle, pero lo mismo hay alguna función que sea inmediata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es lo mejor, si ya tienes todo en una lista, siempre va a ser más cómodo manejarlo así. Sin embargo, podrías usar `assign()` para extraer los valores y asignarlo a un nombre de variable definido dinámicamente:

```
for (i in 1:length(lista)) {
  varname <- paste0("d",i)
  assign(varname, lista[[i]])
}

rm(lista)
```